# Is there a way to set file in SVN repo. to be auto ignored on checkout?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, project

I would like to include my project files and other config files within my SVN repo. but don't want the changes committed back into the repo. So is there a way to set files on the server/repo. end so that when they are checked out they will be automatically ignored?

Comment: Why add the files if you don't want them to be versioned?

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to solve this is don't put the *real* configuration files in the repository. Instead of having

```
config/whatever.cfg
```

in your repository, store

```
config/whatever.cfg.example
```

and then manually copy the `config/whatever.cfg.example` to `config/whatever.cfg` when you check out the repository and set it up for your local environment.

Comment: This how the [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit) says to address the situation as well.